# Rotate Animation on multiple ImageViews

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation, duration

I'd like to assign 28 different rotation animations to 28 different views, and start them when  activity starts. Animations should all have random startOffset and Duration.
I've tried with this code, but it seems that all the animations have the same values anyway.

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.9f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

ImageView imageView;

Random r = new Random();
int delayOffset = 0;
int rotationDuration = 200;


for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

    rotate.reset();

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(ids[i]);
    imageView.clearAnimation();

    delayOffset = r.nextInt(500 - 0);
    rotationDuration = r.nextInt(10000 - 200) + 200;


    rotate.setStartOffset(delayOffset);
    rotate.setDuration(rotationDuration);


    imageView.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try making a new instance of RotateAnimation inside your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the exact same instance of the animation , so all of the views are starting it with the most updated value .

you should create a totally new animation for each of the views.

Comment: Sounds like it'll work.I'll try that later today. But it seems a little overkill to me using 28 animation instances - when I only need to change 2 properties.

Comment: it's only pure data classes , so it's ok . if you target only to API 11 and above , you can use the new animations API which might be easier for you to use , though i never tried it. it should be much faster & smoother since it uses the GPU .